# OOP with Java : avoiding to duplicate code

Tags: java, oop

I would like to override `toString()` method of several personnal exceptions which are of type `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.

Say that I would like to display `test` with `toString()` methods for both `Exception` and `RuntimeException` sub-classes. I have to override `toString()` one time only so.

How can I do it because Java doesn't support multi inheritance please ? I just don't want to write 2 times `toString()` method for both type of exceptions...

Example :

```
public class SubClassOfException extends Exception {

    ...

   @Override
   public String toString() {   
      return "test";
   }

}
```

My goal is to create `SubClassOfRuntimeException` and benefit of the custom `toString()` method of `SubClassOfException` because `RuntimeException` is a sub-class of `Exception`.

Is there a way to do it or I have to duplicate `toString()` code into `SubClassOfException` and `SubClassOfRuntimeException` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `SubClassOfException` is hierarchical on the same level as `RuntimeException`, you cannot share the `toString()` method via inheritance.

But you don't need to duplicate the code either, if both `toString()` methods in your concrete exception types delegate the actual string building to a common "exception string builder". I mean something like

```
class ExceptionPrinter {
    public static String exceptionToString(Exception e) { ... }
}
```

and in both exception classes

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ExceptionPrinter.exceptionToString(this);
}
```

Comment: yep I did that but I would have find another way with inheritance but if it's not possible I will do that, thx ;)

Comment: I see, but unfortunately it's not possible, because inheritance can only work up- or (to be precise) downwards, never horizontal.

Comment: hmm thank you to notice that. It's logical but I didn't know this "rule"